# How can I give the string entered in the textbox as name of pdf file in vs c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a project that converts the datagridview in my project into a pdf file. So, here is the code for creating a pdf file:

```
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("c://Users//realestore//Desktop//Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();
```

So, instead of giving default name as 'Test.pdf' for the pdf file, is there any way to give the name which the user enter in a textbox?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass any file path you'd like to the `FileStream`.

If you want to use the value from a `TextBox`, you can do so like this:

```
new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"c:\Users\realestore\Desktop", textBox1.Text),
               FileMode.Create);
```

Better yet, if you want to use the logged-in user's Desktop instead of "realestore":

```
var userDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

new FileStream(Path.Combine(userDesktop, textBox1.Text), FileMode.Create);
```

Comment: Excuse me, an exception called 'NotSupportedException' is shown on executing this. What will be the problem..?

Comment: i got it.. Thanks.. It was because I added illegal characters to the textboxes which cannot be used for naming files.